# Add view contents to pdf page to pdf in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf-generation

I want to add the contents of the view to pdf at a preferred position on my pdf page.Right now i am using

```
[printview.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```

which cannot satisfy my requirement of adding to the specific position in the pdf page.Anybody have some workaround??please explain.
I know about the documentation available .gone through it .but need help.

also what to do if i need to add two views in the same pdf page generated by the same view ??

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

This code allows you to define a rect in which the pdf is drawn:

```
const CGRect mediaBox = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, drawingWidth, drawingHeight);
CGContextRef pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreate(dataConsumer, &mediaBox, NULL);
```

If you need more help, just ask.

Comment: can you explain a little bit more ??

Comment: @LithuThiruvathira If you subclass the UIView and create a pdf context in the drawRect method, this should draw a Pdf with the rect you provide.  For more info, I would suggest watching the Quartz 2d video from Brad Larson's advanced iPhone development courses: http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/advanced-iphone-development/id407243028 He gets to the part about pdf contexts he gets to Pdf contexts at about 24 minutes in, but I would suggest watching up until then.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you render the pdf into a UIImage, then it's easy to move it around/animate it as you wish. Of course then you looks the benefit of pdf, that it is zoomable, so you could combine a UIImageView and a CATiledLayer.

I did exactly that in a commercial iOS library. My class is called PSPDFPageView and uses both the image and the tiled layer to have both a fast display (image) and great zooming (CATiledLayer). Of course, for the zooming to work you need to put that into a [scrollview][3] too.

w/o more code I can't help you further on this, but you now should get the idea on how to build sth like this.